# Android 11 storage issues

Tags: java, android

I have to migrate the app from android 10 (API level 29) to android 11 (API level 30) according to new Google policy.
And now I have an issue with lunching the camera for taking a picture.

Here is my code:

```
    private File imageFile;
    private void createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";

    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );
    imageFile = image;
  }
```

When I'm creating the temporary file it throws an exception (only in Google and Motorola phones) or . What I need to do to make it work?

Comment: What exception you got ?? update your question with more details.

Comment: I don't have the exception because I don't have Google or Motorola. But I do know that this line do not work properly with API level 30, it's just like a known issue but I was not able to solve it.

Comment: Did you read [this page on storage changes in Android 11](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage)? It's a major change in how storage works, so copy-pasting a couple of lines of code is not a good idea if you don't understand the underlying change.

Comment: @zak_p: what do you mean by "don't have Google or Motorola"? Then reproduce the problem in the Android 11 device emulator and see what the exception is. How do you plan to fix this if you can't verify if the fix worked?!

Comment: `getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)` is usable under scoped storage as always. I see no reason that your code would not work. No permissions needed also. It should work.

Comment: `And now I have an issue with lunching the camera for taking a picture.` No. Not at all. You have a problem with creating a file in getExternalFilesDir(). (That it is a bad idea to create a file already is another story which we can discuss later if your problem is solved).

Comment: Compare values of `getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath()` and `getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();` The `Pictures` directory should be created just by calling that function. But maybe you better check: `if (!storageDir.exists()) if ( !storageDir.mkdirs()) return false;`

Comment: `don't have the exception because I don't have Google or Motorola. ` You should display the exception message in a Toast so users of such devices can tell you. You can also start ACTION_SEND with the message.